# C++ only 2 loop iterations

Tags: c++

I'm studying at university and we started programming in C++. I had some basic concepts about Java (variables, loops and more easy things) and I tried to practice on my own with Microsoft Visual Studio, but I had a problem, this is my code, is a program that tries to guess the number you are thinking of.

```
void main(){
srand(time(NULL));
int number=1+rand()%100;
int highLow;
bool a;
a = true;
cout << "Think a number between 1 and 100 and I will guess it" << endl;
system("PAUSE");
cout << "\nIs it ";
cout << number;
cout << "?" << endl;
cout << "If the number is lower press 1, higher 2 and correct 3" << endl;
cin >> highLow;
while (a)
{
    if (highLow == 1)
    {
        number = 1 + rand() % number;
        cout << "\nIs it ";
        cout << number;
        cout << "?" << endl;
        cin >> highLow;
    }
    else if (highLow == 2)
    {
        number = rand() % (100 - number+1)+number;
        cout << "\nIs it ";
        cout << number;
        cout << "?" << endl;
        cin >> highLow;
    }
    else if (highLow == 3)
        cout << "I win this time" << endl;
        a = false;}
}
```

The problem is that it should ask the user as many times as needed to guess the number, but it only does 2 times, then stops. Can you help me please?

Comment: _"Can you help me please?"_ I think your debugger can be of much more help here. Learn to use your tools.

Comment: `void main()` – please don't. `main()` returns `int`.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0vDKXIq_9A and thank me later.

Comment: use debugging tool !!

Comment: If you write down some pseudo code (i.e. regular language), then coding this becomes easier. Also, it allows anyone that understands your language to proofread the description of the algorithm. Keep this pseudo-code as comments above the according code to remind you of what the code should do. This strategy simply divides the task of programming in two, one being the design, the other being the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If only you had indented your code properly…**

The last `a = false;` statement executes no matter what, because it's outside the scope of the last `else if` statement. Basically, this:

```
else if (highLow == 3)
    cout << "I win this time" << endl;
    a = false;
```

means the following:

```
else if (highLow == 3) {
    cout << "I win this time" << endl;
}

a = false;
```

You need to add some curly braces where appropriate.